# Identify maximum difference in Matrix

Tags: matrix, column

i am trying to find the Maximum difference between two matrices and identify where this maximum occurs.

I illustrate what I mean using an example.
Given

```
X={{3, 1}, {8, 2}, {10, 3}}
Y={{5, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}}
```

I calculate matrix which has (X-Y) and position as entries, specifically

```
d={{-2, 1}, {4, 2}, {5, 3}}
```

As out pout I would like to have

```
{5,3}
```

What is the best way to code this?

Comment: `Ordering[Abs[X[[All, 1]] - X[[All, 2]]], -1][[1]]` should give the the position `3`. The value of the difference can than be found easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your taste,

```
d = MapThread[{#1[[1]] - #2[[1]], #1[[2]]} &, {X, Y}]
```

or

```
d = Transpose@{X[[All, 1]] - Y[[All, 1]], X[[All, 2]]}
```

define the differences `d`, if you need them. The symbol [`D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Differentiation.html) is already in use in *Mathematica*, don't use it for variables.

Then you can compute

```
MaximalBy[d, Abs@*Last]
```

> {{5, 3}}

As @HenrikSchumacher comments you don't really need the intermediate `d` though, and you don't need the second elements in each entry denoting their position: using `Ordering` is more elegant:

```
X = {3, 8, 10};
Y = {5, 4, 5};
j = First@Ordering[Abs[X - Y], -1]
```

> 3

```
(X - Y)[[j]]
```

> 5

Comment: Thank you so much